# Changing git config's http.sslCAInfo has no effect on clone command's certificat verify location

Tags: windows, git, ssl, https

I'm working with Git For Windows (2.17.0.windows.1) on Windows 10 and have run into a conspicuous problem.

I open a Git Bash window in C:\temp and attempt to clone a git repo with the following command:

> git clone
>   https://username@git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/repo1

I see the following error message:

```
> Cloning into 'HelloWorld'... 
> fatal: unable to access 'https://username@git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/repo1': error setting certificate verify locations:   
> CAfile: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
> CApath: none
```

A quick check and it's obvious that the CAfile path is wrong.  It should be:

> C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt

So I attempt to correct if with the following git command:

> git config --system http.sslCAInfo 'C:/Program
>   Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt'

I also try:

> git config --global http.sslCAInfo 'C:/Program
>   Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt'

The change seemed to have no immediate effect.  So I closed the console and reopened it.  Still no change in the error message quoted above.  The CAfile path reported by the error message remains inccorect.

Anyone have a clue what is going wrong here?

Comment: Did you try `git config --global http.sslCAInfo C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt`

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but if you read the description above...I already tried that.

Comment: Notice the missing single quotes in my suggestion. `'C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt'` is not necessarily the same as `C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt`